# Top 10 win probabilities

Tags: probability, distributions, python, statsmodels

I am a newbie here, hoping to find the right response for my question. I have a task at my hand to create some kind of model that can help me to determine what is the chance of winning a certain amount from a given bid.
For eg: Top 10 opportunities looks like below

[image]

I want to answer a question which says What is the percentage of winning a deal of value 200M(number might change-this is as per users input) out of this 10 deals in total?
Hoping to find win/lose probability in 1/0 out of 2 to the power of 10 such possibilities for each company.

Please let me know if I need to explain it more. I am trying to get a solution out in Python.

Edit:
This data was collected from sales person, As per his input collecting 700M, he is 50% confident he will get the amount, which comes upto 350 in Weighted Bid. Now if I run this scenario 2 power 10 times, I will get 1024 scenarios if we would be able to get the bidding amount, which would be either 1 or 0.

Similarly do it for other companies. Can anyone help.

Comment: This will be impossible to answer without more information about how the data were collected and what they mean.  Please edit your post to include some explanation.

Comment: @whuber I have edited my reponse. Hope you are getting my point. Can any algorithm can achieve this scenario.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what you are trying to ask or what your data even mean.  One guess is that you are considering the distribution of the sum of ten binary random variables specified by the ten rows.  But what is your question? The sum is worked out, as you suggest, by considering all $2^{10}=1024$ scenarios.  "Can anyone help" leaves us in the dark concerning what kind of answers you are looking for.

Comment: I am trying to understand what is the probability of winning a deal of certain amount if I run the scenario 2**10 instances.